# python3 checking and moving using os.path.exists and shutil.move using wild cards or match with number

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, matching, shutil

I'm trying to see if a file exists using the below code. The problem is that there is a number in the file that changes upon the generation of the file and I don't know how to match against the file where the name changes.
The file name is FD 464738 - DailyReport.xlsx the existing code:

```
#Match and find if file exists
while not os.path.exists('/home/jobsuser/Downloads/FD 464738 - DailyReport.xlsx'):
    time.sleep(1)

#Move and rename file
shutil.move('/home/jobsuser/Downloads/FD 464738 - DailyReport.xlsx', '/home/jobsuser/files/DailyFDReport_'+fnameyesterday+'.xlsx')
```

I've tried replacing the number portion with a wildcard * and which did not work.
Looking for any suggestion that will allow the match and move to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/home/jobsuser/Downloads')
while list(path.glob('FD * - DailyReport.xlsx')) == []:
    time.sleep(1)

files = list(path.glob('FD * - DailyReport.xlsx'))
shutil.move(files[0], ...)
```

There are a few unknowns, so there is certainly room for improvements.

Comment: This worked great for me. I did have to work around the path issue error by casting the file to a string in the shutil.move :
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'rstrip'